# Chrome and IE browsers not displaying datauri string (pdf)

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, pdf, iframe, jspdf

I'm generating pdf using **jspdf.js**.

It returned a datauri string(pdf) something like this

```
data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJAyNwovUm9vdCAyNiAwIFIKL0luZm8gMjUgMCBSCj4+CnN0YXJ0eHJlZgo1MDMzMzMKJSVFT0Y...
```

I tried to display this pdf in iframe and new tab.

I used the following code for displaying pdf in iframe:

```
$('#iframeid').attr('src', x);   // here variable x contains datauri string
```

I used the following code for displaying pdf in new tab:

```
doc.output('dataurlnewwindow'); //i.e. used jspdf's output() to display it in new tab
```

It's working fine in Mozilla Firefox. But, **not working in Chrome and IE browsers**.

Why Chrome and IE browsers not displaying datauri string(pdf) ?

Answer (score 1):

- Internet Explorer was not supporting `datauri` before version 8 and the later versions are also having limitation for data length (see comments [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(v=vs.85).aspx))
- Google Chrome had some issues in v.42 limiting `datauri` to 128K length. It was fixed but in v.49 may have these limitations again as [reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462466/php-inline-pdf-output-in-google-chrome-issue-with-pdfs-above-150k/).

Please also take in account real `datauri` data size as it uses `base64` encoding that leads to the increase of the data length by additional `+25%`.